# intermittent login problems with flask-login

Tags: python, cookies, flask, flask-login

here is my code where I try to login a user via Flask-login api. user fills the user/pwd and is logged in via flask-api. I get my customised message that user has logged in meaning I have g.user i not none and g.user.is-autheticated=true. I can also see the session cookie the response headers.

```
@lm.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    app.logger.info(str(User.query.get(int(user_id))))
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = current_user

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(64))

    def __init__(self, username="", email="", password=""):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def get_id(self):
       return self.id

    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.username


@app.route('/weblogin',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def weblogin():
   app.logger.info(str(g.user))
   app.logger.info(str(g.user.is_authenticated()))


   if request.method == 'POST':
    usr = request.form['login']
    pwd = request.form['password']
    session['remember_me'] = request.form['remember_me']
    user=db.session.query(User).filter_by(username=usr).first()
    if user.password == pwd:
      remember_me = False
      if 'remember_me' in session:
        remember_me = session['remember_me']
        session.pop('remember_me', None)
      login_user(user, remember = remember_me)
      g.user=user
      app.logger.info(str(g.user))
      app.logger.info(str(g.user.is_authenticated()))
      app.logger.info(str(g.user.username))
      return str(current_user.is_authenticated())
      return "logging user in"
    else:
      return "wrong username password combination"
   elif g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated():
     return "you are already logger in"
   else:
     return render_template("login.html")
```

now the strange bit is If I try to close the window and open a new one. And go the loginpage the application fails to authenticate me sometime. though I see the same cookie being sent to the server. The app "sometimes" fails to load the user. and I get redirected to login page asking to fill in the credentials.

after a bit of fiddling with the app I observed that If I try to refresh the page few times app is able to authenticate me fine. I see my message that I have been logged in again. Though I have not done anything different.

It would be really grateful if someone can point me what I am doing wrong here.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried to **not** pass the user through the `g` object? In a similar setting, I just access `current_user` directly in the `@app.route` functions where I need it.